# Save .txt file in local folder by python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want build a program to save some documents file.
My program run in test folder and i want to save Documents in test\save.
I use these way:

```
File=open("C:\\test\\save\\hello.txt",'w')
File.write("hello world")
File.close()
```

Now i copy my program to E driver and run the program then hello.txt make in C driver not in E drive.
What should i do to save documents every where past my test folder??

Comment: did you try `open("test\\save\\hello.txt",'w')`?

Comment: Make sure your path is correct. Whether that's the drive - C:, E:, D:, etc. or your folders.

Comment: Did you mean: ‘File=open("\\test\\save\\hello.txt",'w')’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the program writing to that absolute file path. If you want it to run in a given directory, just have the name of the file like `hello.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

**I guess you want something like this:**

```
from os.path import dirname, realpath, join

your_current_app_directory = dirname(realpath(__file__))
your_custom_folder = "test"

with open(join(your_current_app_directory, your_custom_folder, "hello.txt"), "w") as export:
    export.write("hello")
```

it will be dynamic; depends on your app directory.